# How to test(assert) intermediate states of a React Component which uses hooks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, use-effect

*This question is regarding: how to test a component which uses the `useEffect` hook and the `useState` hook, using the `react-testing-library`.*

I have the following component:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
     // 'request' is an async call which takes ~2seconds to complete
     request().then(() => {
        setState(1);
     });
  }, [state]);

  return <div>{state}</div>
}
```

When I render this application, the behavior I see is as follows:

1. **The app initially renders `0`**
2. After ~2seconds, the app renders `1`

Now, I want to test and assert this behavior using the `react-testing-library` and `jest`.

This is what I have so far:

```js
import {render, act} from '@testing-library/react';

// Ignoring the describe wrapper for the simplicity
test('MyComponent', async () => {
  let result;
  await act(async () => {
    result = render(<MyComponent />);
  });
  expect(result.container.firstChild.textContent).toBe(1);
})
```

The test passes. **However, I also want to assert the fact that the user initially sees the app rendering `0` (before it renders `1` after 2 seconds).**

How do I do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jest can [timetravel](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) but if you can't replace your request call with a mock then i'm afraid it won't do you any good, you could consider if you shouldn't rather concentrate on testing the call and the behavior of the component without taking into account that there is a long running request

Comment: Thank you very much for the response @Icepickle. Yes, I could time travel. But then again, what I want to test is the initial state. Time-traveling would indeed make the test better. But as far as I understand, it doesn't let me test the state I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Sunil Pai in this blog: https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md

Here's how I managed to solve this:

```js
import {request} from '../request';

jest.mock('../request');

test('MyComponent', async () => {
  let resolve;
  request.mockImplementation(() => new Promise(resolve => { 
    // Save the resolver to a local variable
    // so that we can trigger the resolve action later
    resolve = _resolve;
  }));

  let result;
  await act(async () => {
    result = render(<MyComponent />);
  });

  // Unlike the non-mocked example in the question, we see '0' as the result
  // This is because the value is not resolved yet
  expect(result.container.firstChild.textContent).toBe('0');

  // Now the setState will be called inside the useEffect hook
  await act(async () => resolve());

  // So now, the rendered value will be 1
  expect(result.container.firstChild.textContent).toBe('1');
})
```